# Exporting a dictionary with 'type' and 'size' columns in python

Tags: python, dictionary, export

I'm between beginner and intermediate in python.  I'm not sure how to best recreate the problem, but I have a code that outputs a dictionary item with the following:

```
Key         Type        size        Value
 'a'         set         2          'email 1, email 2'
 'b'         set        28          'email 1, email 2, email 3,...,email 28' 
 'c'         set        19          'email 1, email 2, email 3, ..., email 19'

etc, etc.
```

I've looked around and successfully output the keys and the first 2 values.  However, I would love to output the 'size' column.  I can skip the 'type' column as it just says 'set'.

Please let me know your thoughts, appreciate any guidance you can provide.

Comment: That dictionary output is not clear, can you edit your post to format the dictionary content.

Comment: Convert the dictionary into dataframe and export the relevant columns

Comment: @RajatMishra how do I export the relevant columns? I can work around the fact that the arrays are not all the same length, but in converting it to a dataframe, it throws an error that 'arrays must all be the same length'

Comment: @zangru, could you share the code that outputs this dictionary item?

Comment: @CavinDsouza I actually found a really easy workaround.  Just copy and paste the dictionary into excel one column at a time.  I'm using spyder 4 via the anaconda workspace, so it lets me do that.  Thank you for checking in!